# Why divide regularization factor by size of dataset?

Tags: regression, regularization, linear-regression

Suppose I'm trying to minimize a cost function:

$$ J(\theta) = \frac {1} {2m} \sum _{i = 1}^ m (h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 $$

Adding regularization, as seen [here](http://www.holehouse.org/mlclass/07_Regularization.html), we get:

$$ J(\theta) = \frac {1} {2m} [\sum _{i = 1}^ m (h_\theta (x^{(i)}) - y^{(i)})^2 + \lambda \sum_{i = 1}^n  \theta_i^2] $$

My question is: why is the regularization factor also divided by $2m$?

Comment: Such division is notational only. You can divide $\lambda$ by $2m$ and make $\lambda$ larger, or do not divide $\lambda$ by $2m$ and make $\lambda$ smaller. It doesn't matter